# How to create a Parent property for Children of an ObservableCollection TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I have a `TreeView` in my program that is implemented through an `ObservableCollection`. I use a ViewModel to initialize and perform operations on the tree. The previously mentioned ViewModel is attached to a Data Model that has properties for all of the common elements in the Tree.

One of the properties in my `TreeView`'s data model is `Children`:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataModel> _children;

public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Children
{
    get { return _children ?? (_children = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>()); }
    set { _children = value; }
}
```

I would like to know how to create a parent property for these child nodes, so that when I create new ones I can define the parent.

TreeViewViewModel:

```
//This is where the nodes are created
private DataModel CreateNode()
{
    return new DataModel()
    {
        Children = 
        { 
            new DataModel() { Parent = /*After creating the property, how would I set the parent?**/ }
        },
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean.

But it seems you have DataModel inside DataModel and so on.

Now you asking how to get the parent, right?. Well simply set parent when creating next node.

```
private DataModel CreateNode(DataModel parentNode)
{
    return new DataModel()
    {
        Children = 
        { 
            new DataModel() { Parent = parentNode }
        },
    };
}
```